# Handle 404 responses correctly using Laravel + Vue

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

I am new to Vue and I do not know the correct way to handle 404 responses using api routes.

In my routes > web.php I have:

```
Route::get('/{any}', function(){
return view('app');})->where('any', '.*');
```

To route every request to a single entry point which I then handle through Vue router.

In my routes > api.php I have:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/listings/{listing}', 'ListingController@show')->name('listing');
...(more routes)
```

which get some data from my controllers and return a json response.

Let's say I hit `https://example.com/notexistingroute`

That route will pass the web.php routes as it exists in the where condition applied `->where('any', '.*');`

And then it will fail in my api routes so I will catch that error and I could show a 404 component to the user, but `https://example.com/nonexistingroute`returned a 200 status code to the browser which is not good for seo.

I understand I need to add an extra filter to my web.php routes or something like that but not sure how...

Comment: You cannot achieve this without using server side rendering to allow a proxy to determine the validity of a front end route by parsing the routes from vue, unless you use express as a middleware to proxy between laravel and then once the route is confirmed proxy the request to laravel otherwise return a 404 from the middleware proxy.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will rethink the way I am building the app then